# Java integer division doesn't give floor for negative numbers

Tags: java, integer, floor

I was trying to use java's integer division, and it supposedly takes the floor. However, it rounds towards zero instead of the floor.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(-1 / 100); // should be -1, but is 0
        System.out.println(Math.floor(-1d/100d)); // correct
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not want to convert to a double/float because it needs to be efficient. I'm trying to solve this with a method, `floorDivide(long a, long b)`. What I have is:

```
static long floorDivide(long a, long b) {
    if (a < 0) {
        // what do I put here?
    }
    return a / b;
}
```

How can I do this without a double/float?

Comment: There's nothing inefficient about casting one of your `ints` to `double`.

Answer (score 12):

[`floorDiv()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-) from Java.Math that does exactly what you want.

> ```
> static long floorDiv(long x, long y)
> ```
>
> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) long value that is less than or equal to the algebraic quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Take the absolute value, divide it, multiply it by -1.

Weird bug.

Comment: That's not a bug, multiple way to compute a quotient/remainder exists. The one that rounds toward -1 is the euclidean division, while Java uses a truncated division.

Comment: Doesn't work with something like `-1 / 4`. It gives 0 when I want -1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  int i = (int) Math.round(doubleValToRound);
```

It will return a `double` value that you can cast into an `int` without lost of precission and without performance problems (casts haven't a great computational cost)

Also it's equivalent to

```
 int a = (int) (doubleValToRound + 0.5);
 //in your case
 System.out.println((int) ((-1 / 100) + 0.5));
```

With this last one you won't have to enter into tedious and unnecesary "if" instructions. Like a good suit, its valid for every moment and has a higher portability for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but meets the requirement to not use a double/float. Really you should just cast it to a double.

The logic here is take the floor of a negative result from the integer division if it doesn't divide evenly.

```
static long floorDivide(long a, long b)
{
    if(a % b != 0 && ((a < 0 && b > 0) || (a > 0 && b < 0)))
    {
        return (a / b - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (a / b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the two integers. then add -1 to the result (in case the absolute value of both numerator and denominator are not same). For example -3/3 gives you -1, the right answer without adding -1 to the division.

Answer (score 0):

Since a bit late, but you need to convert your parameters to **long** or **double**

```
int result = (int) Math.floor( (double) -1 / 5 );
// result == -1
```

This worked for me elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`floorDiv()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv(int,int)) for a general case, as Frank Harper suggested.

Note, however, that when the divisor is a power of 2, the division is often substituted by a right shift by an appropriate number of bits, i.e.

```
x / d
```

is the same as

```
x >> p
```

when p = 0,1,...,30 (or 0,1,...,62 for longs), d = 2<sup>p</sup> and x is non-negative. This is not only more effective than ordinary division but gives the right result (in mathematical sense) when x is negative.